# About javascript scope?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have something like this:

```
function f(parameter){
  //does something, not really important
}
var swtch = "0";
f({
  a: function(){
      swtch = "1";
      }
   });
   
   console.log(swtch);
```

The console prints out 0. How can I make it print 1?

Comment: how do I execute the second function then?

Answer (score 3):

the a() function is not executed, so the value of `swtch` is not changed.

you need to execute the a() function

```js
function f(parameter){
    parameter.a()
}

var swtch = "0";

f({ a: function() { swtch = "1"; } });
   
console.log(swtch);
```